# Unable to write a deprecation for the change of a class name in a gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

wordpress newbie here,

I have a block called "abc" that I want to write a deprecation for. I want to essentially change the class name of the root component.

Here is the new save function

```
import {RichText, InnerBlocks, useBlockProps} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import {Icon} from '@wordpress/components';

import {abcIcons} from '../../assets/icons';

import './style.scss';

export default function save(props) {
    const {attributes} = props;

    const result = <div className={"SOME_OTHER_CLASSNAME"}>
        <div className={'abc_defbox-definition'}>
            <div
                className={'abc_defbox-icon-wrapper'}
                style={{fill: attributes.color}}
            >
                <Icon icon={abcIcons[attributes.icon]}/>
            </div>
            <RichText.Content
                tagName={'span'}
                className={'abc_defbox-header'}
                value={attributes.header}
                style={{color: attributes.color}}
            />
        </div>
        <InnerBlocks.Content/>
    </div>

    console.log(result)

    return (
        result
    );
}
```

Here is the deprecated.js

```
import {RichText, InnerBlocks, useBlockProps, InspectorControls, ColorPalette} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import {Icon, SelectControl, Tip} from '@wordpress/components';

import {abcIcons} from '../../assets/icons';

import './style.scss';

const v1 = {
    save(props) {
        const {attributes} = props;

        const result = <div className={"abc_defbox"}>
            <div className={'abc_defbox-definition'}>
                <div
                    className={'abc_defbox-icon-wrapper'}
                    style={{fill: attributes.color}}
                >
                    <Icon icon={abcIcons[attributes.icon]}/>
                </div>
                <RichText.Content
                    tagName={'span'}
                    className={'abc_defbox-header'}
                    value={attributes.header}
                    style={{color: attributes.color}}
                />
            </div>
            <InnerBlocks.Content/>
        </div>

        console.log("V1", result)

        return (
            result
        );
    }

}

export default [v1];
```

Here is the index.js file

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

import name from './block.json';
import edit from './edit';
import save from './save';
import { abcIcons } from '../../assets/icons';
import deprecated from './deprecated'

registerBlockType( name, {
    icon: abcIcons.default,
    edit,
    save,
    deprecated
} );
```

This is what is happening in the editor:

```
Block validation: Expected attribute `class` of value `SOME_OTHER_CLASSNAME`, saw `abc_defbox`.

Block validation: Block validation failed for `abc/defbox` ({name: 'abc/defbox', icon: {…}, keywords: Array(0), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="SOME_OTHER_CLASSNAME"><div class="abc_defbox-definition"><div class="abc_defbox-icon-wrapper" style="fill:#919191"><svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="24" height="24" class="dashicons" aria-hidden="true"><rect width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect y="13.24" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect y="26.49" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect x="13.15" y="13.24" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect x="13.15" y="26.49" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect x="13.15" y="39.73" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect></svg></div><span class="abc_defbox-header" style="color:#919191">This is not a test title.hjbksd changeasdadadXXXs</span></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="abc_defbox"><div class="abc_defbox-definition"><div class="abc_defbox-icon-wrapper" style="fill:#919191"><svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="24" height="24" class="dashicons" aria-hidden="true"><rect width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect y="13.24" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect y="26.49" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect x="13.15" y="13.24" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect x="13.15" y="26.49" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect><rect x="13.15" y="39.73" width="10.16" height="10.27"></rect></svg></div><span class="abc_defbox-header" style="color:#919191">This is not a test title.hjbksd changeasdadadXXXs</span></div>

</div>
```

I hope somebody can help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to do it correctly
Cheers,
Niko

I tried to change the classname and I expected what I did to be enough for the deprecation api to handle the changes